# How to restart service tomcat in solaris?

Tags: tomcat7, solaris, opensolaris

Hello Today I have problem related to restart service apache tomcat in solaris ? Can you help me about cmd to restart?

Comment: i install it already , and i worked. But when I config user tomcat , they need  to restart . And I try googling , no result found.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you originally installed Tomcat on your Solaris server. Below I'm providing two different answers depending on how you've installed Tomcat.

#### As a SMF service

Assumption: You have installed Tomcat using Solaris' IPS package manager. (which also means you're on a fairly recent version of Solaris, not an ancient one)

In that case it will be installed as a [true service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Management_Facility) in Solaris and restarting will be done just like any other service in Solaris, namely

```
$ svcadm restart <servicename>
```

example:

```
$ svcadm restart network/http:tomcat8
```

#### As a standalone thingy not integrated with Solaris' SMF feature

Assumption: You've simply just downloaded the tarballs and unpacked them on the server.

In this case you'll have to rely directly on Tomcat's own start/stop scripts which you can find in Tomcat's `bin` directory. You cannot do a restart directly, so what you do is:

```
$ bin/shutdown.sh
$ bin/startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Example commands,

1. svcadm disable tomcat
2. svcs tomcat
3. svcadm clear tomcat
4. svcadm enable tomcat
5. svcadm restart tomcat
6. svcadm enable tomcat